# JavaScript append text using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to reuse the code from here [Edit a variable within an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171044/edit-a-variable-within-an-array/26171413#26171413) to create something simmilar but less complex.

I made the 'working' function:

```
var WorkT = function(gain,loss,message) {
    coins += this.gain;
    coins -= this.loss;
    this.message = message;
}


workT1 = new WorkT(30,0,'<span class="red">+ 30 Gold Coins');
workT2 = new WorkT(15,0,'<span class="red">+ 15 Gold Coins');
workT3 = new WorkT(80,0,'<span class="red">+ 80 Gold Coins');
workT4 = new WorkT(1,0,'<span class="red">+ 1 Gold Coin');

WorkTs = [workT1,workT2,workT3,workT4];
```

And I'm trying to call it later on in my code with this:

```
$('#output').html(WorkTs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)].WorkT());
```

But, when I click the button, nothing changes. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You're overwriting your `WorkT` variable.

Comment: @YoannM whoops, you're right. forgot the 'S' in the array. Sorry, added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WorkT` instances have no `WorkT()` function.

You need to declare a function named `WorkT` (or else) inside your `WorkT` 'class' :

```
var WorkT = function(gain,loss,message) {
    //...
    this.work = function () {
        //Do Something.
    }
}
```

Or you won't be able to call it on your instances :

```
$('#output').html(WorkT[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)].work());
```

It all depends on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I over looked that!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors in your code.

1. What is the `coins` in the `WorkT` Constructor? Is it a global variable, or you wanted to do `this.coins`?
2. `this.gain` and `this.loss` does not exist. They are just `gain` and `loss`.
3. There is no function called `WorkT` in the class `WorkT`. You probably want to define the function, too.

Here is how the code will look like, assuming `coins` is a global variable.

```
var WorkT = function(gain,loss,message) {
    coins += gain;
    coins -= loss;
    this.message = message;

    this.work = function(){
        //Do something here.
    }
}
```

And,

```
$('#output').html(WorkTs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)].work());
```